# 本番環境と開発環境のスキーマ差分管理

Tags: php, laravel

PHPにおいて、
開発環境で変更したテーブルのスキーマを本番環境にもプログラマブルに反映させたいのですが、どのような管理がおすすめでしょうか？
PHPのLaravelを使っているので、マイグレーションファイルで管理すべきというのはわかるのですが、他に手段がないものかと思いまして。

そもそもRailsやlaravel等のフルスタックなフレームワークを使ってる人はきちんとマイグレーションファイルで管理してるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Laravelのようにフレームワーク付属のORMライブラリにマイグレーションツールが付属している場合は、それが使われていることが多いです。

このマイグレーションの本番環境への適用をプログラマブルに、という点は、昨今のデプロイツールであればカスタムコマンドやフレームワーク向けのサブコマンドで対応可能です。

- [Deploying a Laravel Application Using Capistrano](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/deploying-a-laravel-application-using-capistrano--net-35685)
- [PHPのためのCapistrano風デプロイツール「Rocketeer」でLaravelをデプロイする](http://atijusts.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/18/175531)

Answer (score 1):

Rails についてのみ、回答を付け加えておきます。

Rails では、よほどのことがない限り、完全にマイグレーションファイル(db/migrate/ 下) に任せます。
そうやって定形処理をする(レールに乗る)ことが Rails の存在意義です。